# Does phonegap javascript need to be added to the DOM before the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered?

Tags: cordova, hybrid, domcontentloaded

Cordova-2.2.0.js is included in initial html page that the app loads on startup.  After the deviceready event is triggered, an external .aspx page is loaded using
    "window.location.href = "http://myurl.aspx";"

If the loaded page includes a script tag for cordova.js then deviceready fires and everything works fine.  However, the user might be on an iOS device or an Android device.  So cordova.js needs to be dynamically added to the page.  Cordova.js is always downloaded to the device but sometimes the external url cannot connect with cordova's api on the device.  I have experienced this problem on an iPad.

When the app works fine I notice that cordova.js is handling the DOMContentLoaded event, when it doesn't work cordova.js is not catching the event.

Thanks,